# Cannot use any mouse movement packages with python after using image recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

ive been trying to use a script with cv2 and numpy to search an image for an icon, th start button for a stress test software, and that all works fine but it doesnt work together with any mouse movement packages, ive tried mouse, pyautogui, autoit and a few more with no results. the mouse movement works if i put it before the cv2 image recognition script but that wont work cause i need the coordinates.

P.S. 100, 500 is not the coordinates i want to move to, i want to move to the "coords" variable which should be equal to (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import pyautogui
import time
import win32api
import pydirectinput

def movedamnyou():
    pydirectinput.moveTo(100, 500)

#open OCCT
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "open", "D:\AppData\OCCT.exe", None, ".", 0)
#wait for program to open
time.sleep(20)

#classifier
#take screenshot
#im2 = pyautogui.screenshot('scrn.png')
# Read the main image
img_rgb = cv2.imread('scrn.png')
# Convert it to grayscale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Read the template
template = cv2.imread('OCCTico.png', 0)
# Store width and height of template in w and h
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# Perform match operations.
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
# Specify a threshold
threshold = 0.8
# Store the coordinates of matched area in a numpy array
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
# Draw a rectangle around the matched region.
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
# Show the final image with the matched area.
cv2.imshow('Detected', img_rgb)
#print the output position
coords = (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h)
pydirectinput.moveTo(100, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is still not working